# Javascript creates new arrays based on conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js

**I have old and entity arrays：**

```
var old = [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "entity_type_id": 1,
        "product_id": 4,
        "name": "test1",
        "acreage": 100,
        "yield": 20,
        "worth": 30
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "entity_type_id": 1,
        "product_id": 4,
        "name": "test2",
        "acreage": 10,
        "yield": 20,
        "worth": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "entity_type_id": 3,
        "product_id": 5,
        "name": "test3",
        "acreage": 20,
        "yield": 20,
        "worth": 40
    }
]
var entity = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "a1"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "a2"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "a3"}
]
```

**I hope to get the following data：**

```js
var newArr = [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "entity_type_id": 1,
            "product_id": 4,
            "name": "test1",
            "acreage": 110,
            "yield": 40,
            "worth": 30,
            "entity_type_1": 2, // The total amount of entity_type_id (entity_type_id: 1)
            "entity_type_2": 0,
            "entity_type_3": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "entity_type_id": 3,
            "product_id": 5,
            "name": "test3",
            "acreage": 20,
            "yield": 20,
            "worth": 40,
            "entity_type_1": 0,
            "entity_type_2": 0,
            "entity_type_3": 1 // The total amount of entity_type_id (entity_type_id: 3)
        }
    ]
console.log(newArr)
```

**I tried the following code and got some data. I'm not sure if there will be any exceptions or errors.**

**What's more, I don't know how to deal with the entity array data. Can someone help me solve this problem and get the result I expect?**

**Thank you very much ！**

```
function mergeArr(arr) {
    const temp = []
    arr.forEach((dataItem) => {
      if (temp.length) {
        let filterValue = temp.filter((items) => {
          return items.product_id === dataItem.product_id
        })
        if (filterValue.length) {
          temp.forEach((n) => {
            if (n.product_id === filterValue[0].product_id) {
              n.yield = dataItem.yield + filterValue[0].yield
              n.acreage = dataItem.acreage + filterValue[0].acreage
              n.worth = dataItem.worth + filterValue[0].worth
            }
          })
        } else {
          temp.push(dataItem)
        }
      } else {
        temp.push(dataItem)
      }
    })
    return temp
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youi could find the object and sum the wanted properties. For `entity` take another loop and map new entries and build a new object from it for spreading.

```js
var old = [{ id: 3, entity_type_id: 1, product_id: 4, name: "test1", acreage: 100, yield: 20, worth: 30 }, { id: 4, entity_type_id: 1, product_id: 4, name: "test2", acreage: 10, yield: 20, worth: 0 }, { id: 5, entity_type_id: 3, product_id: 5, name: "test3", acreage: 20, yield: 20, worth: 40 }],
    entity = [{ id: 1, name: "a1" }, { id: 2, name: "a2" }, { id: 3, name: "a3" }],
    entityTypes = Object.fromEntries(entity.map(({ id }) => ['entity_type_' + id, 0])),
    result = old.reduce((r, o) => {
        let temp = r.find(q => q.product_id === o.product_id);
        if (!temp) r.push(temp = { ... o, ...entityTypes });
        else ['acreage', 'yield', 'worth'].forEach(k => temp[k] += o[k]);
        temp['entity_type_' + o.entity_type_id]++;        
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I found a problem that if the entity_type_id value of the second element of the old array is 2, executing your method will not get the result I expect.

Comment: I tried to modify it
`let temp = r.find(q => q.entity_type_id === o.entity_type_id || q.product_id === o.product_id); `

I got the results, but I'm not sure if there are any other problems?

Comment: sorry, it was the wrong correlation. with `product_id`, it should work now.